# Is it possible to read DHT22 through I2C ADC (i.e. PCF8591)?

Tags: sensor, adc, i2c

In my application I'm required to read all sensors through I2C bus. No sensors should be connected to MCU directly.

At this moment I need to read temperature and humidity ([DHT22](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Digital+humidity+and+temperature+sensor+AM2302.pdf) sensor). 
In order to read data from DHT22 I need to switch data pin to output first and then after some high/low operations and delay I can switch it to input and read data from sensor.

As an ADC IC I have [PCF8591](https://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCF8591.pdf). I don't quite understand how to achieve this with PCF8591. Is there a way to do so? 
Maybe I should be using other ADC/I2C?

Comment: The link to the DHT22 leads to the datasheet for a MOSFET.

Comment: I wouldn't think so, since the DHT22 uses a single wire protocol instead of i2c.

Comment: The DHT22 has a digital output.  You read it via a digital I/O pin, not via an ADC.

Comment: @JRE: I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in any useful sense. The DHT22 communicates digitally, using a protocol described in the datasheet. It doesn't output an analog temperature signal; if you want that, use another part, like the [LM35](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf).

You can't use an ADC to read the DHT22 because:

1. It's not an analog signal. (I mean, you *could* use an ADC to read a digital signal, but it'd be a huge waste.)
2. The DHT22 doesn't start outputting its status until it receives a pulse from the host MCU. If you hooked it up to an ADC, it'd just sit there and not do anything.